# Table Valued Parameter for function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to pass an array to function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005,
but following code doesn't work:

```
create function TarafhaieGharardad
(
@ShomareGharardad bigint,
@VahedeVagozarKonande int,
@NoeKhedmat int,
@TarafhaieGharardad table(id int)
)
returns table
as 
return
(
    select * from Gharardad
where 
(
(@ShomareGharardad=-1) or (PK#ShomareGharardad=@ShomareGharardad)) and
(@VahedeVagozarKonande=-1) or (FK#VahedeVagozarKonande=@VahedeVagozarKonande)) and
(@NodeKhedmat=-1) or (FK#NodeKhedmat=@NoeKhedmat)) and
(count(@TarafeGharardad)=0) or (FK#TarafeGharardad in(select id from @TarafhaieGharardad))
)
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 does not have Table Valued Parameters. This excellent article by Erland Sommarskog discusses the various options available.

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Comment: But the code is already written for you in the linked article! Just pick one that looks like it has reasonable performance for what you need and use that!

Answer (score 1):

Another good article (from Jeff Moden) about tally tables: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

It shouldn't be too hard, especially if you want to be a pro :)